# Object entries forEach is not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have the following piece of code:

```
<tbody>
  {Object.entries(procedures).forEach(procedure => {
    const [key, value] = procedure
      return (
        <tr key={key}>
          <td className="pt-5">{key}</td>
          <td className="pt-5">
           <button type="button" onClick={() => openModal(value, true)}>
          </td>
        </tr>
      )
</tbody>
```

I can even console.log(value, key), befure the return and it seems right. If I remove the forEach, and change the values/key variables to another thing, it also works. Does someone know what's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). always returns `undefined` ,no matter what you return from. it.

Try with `map`

```
<tbody>
  {Object.entries(procedures).map(procedure => {
    const [key, value] = procedure
      return (
        <tr key={key}>
          <td className="pt-5">{key}</td>
          <td className="pt-5">
           <button type="button" onClick={() => openModal(value, true)}>
          </td>
        </tr>
      )
</tbody>
```

Comment: the thing is, when I console.log(values), it shows the part of the object I want

Comment: Yup you can `console.log() `inside `foreach` but you cannot return anything from it.

Comment: Oh, it worked with .map(). Thank you, Shubh